# Lambdas in FunctionalInterfaces in Java

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

I am trying to make use of lambdas in `Java` but can't understand how it works at all. I created `@FunctionalInterface` like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunctionalInterface {
    String getString(String s);
}
```

now in my code I use the `lambda` as here:

```
MyFunctionalInterface function = (f) -> {
    Date d = new Date();
    return d.toString() + " " + person.name + " used fnc str";
};
```

Next, I want to make use of my `function` passing it into the constructor of another class and use it like this:

```
public SampleClass(MyFunctionalInterface function) {
    String tmp = "The person info: %s";
    this.result = String.format(tmp, function.getString(String.valueOf(function)));
}
```

Why I need to use it the `valueOf()` here? I thought that thanks for this I could use just `function.getString()`?

**Output:**
`Tue Sep 19 11:04:48 CEST 2017 John used fnc str`

Comment: Your function takes a `String` as a parameter. Reading your string format, you should pass the person info as a `String` to it. Right now, you are passing the string representation of the function itself, to the function.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. I would have expected that  lambda definition in the place where you use function. Or that you use a method reference. I think the code you have right now will turn the OBJECT that function also represents and create a string representation of that, which is then passed as input to the function itself. Simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: What is the output of this code?

Comment: @jrook added output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `getString` method requires a `String` argument, so you can't call it without any argument.

That said, your lambda expression ignores that `String` argument and instead takes data from some `person` variable (which you didn't show where you declare it).

Perhaps your functional interface should take a `Person` argument instead:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunctionalInterface {
    String getString(Person p);
}

MyFunctionalInterface function = p -> {
    Date d = new Date();
    return d.toString() + " " + p.name + " used fnc str";
};

public SampleClass(MyFunctionalInterface function, Person person) {
    String tmp = "The person info: %s";
    this.result = String.format(tmp, function.getString(person));
}
```

Alternately, you can remove the argument from your functional interface's method:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunctionalInterface {
    String getString();
}

MyFunctionalInterface function = () -> {
    Date d = new Date();
    return d.toString() + " " + person.name + " used fnc str";
};

public SampleClass(MyFunctionalInterface function) {
    String tmp = "The person info: %s";
    this.result = String.format(tmp, function.getString());
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I cannot pass there a specific object because I would like to format many of them with this `Inerface`, not just a `person` (e.g `car`, `animal` and so on)

Comment: @soommy12 In that case, perhaps you can make the functional interface generic - `interface MyFunctionalInterface<T>`. Of course, if you intend to use specific properties such as p.name, you will have to place some type bound on T  (`<T extends SomeType>` where `SomeType` is a class that has a `name` property). Otherwise, you can remove the argument from the `getString()` method (and from your lambda expression), and keep everything else as is.

Comment: Ok, but another question is can I make my Interface to takes nothing and return `String` then? I mean, I would like to make some kind of "abstract method" in here. I want to do things with the `String` and return it. Can I achieve this by lamdas?

Comment: @soommy12 Of course you can. For example - `MyFunctionalInterface function = () -> {
    Date d = new Date();
    return d.toString() + " " + person.name + " used fnc str";
};`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @soommy12 I added that to the answer.

Comment: @soommy12 Note that many simple functional interfaces are already provided for you in the `java.util.function` package.  The standard interface that consumes nothing but returns a value is `Supplier<T>`.  You need not write your own.